# Last two digits of $12345678910...$ when it is divisible by $72$ the first time.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A very large number is formed by writing consecutive digits this way:
 $$12345678910111213...$$

Find the last two digits of this number when it is divisible by $72$ the first time.

Could anyone advise me on how to approach this problem? Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Well, $72=8\times 9$ so you need to check two divisibilities.  $8$ is easy (just need last three digits divisible by $8$).  That leaves $9$.

Comment: Hint: $72=9*8$, so try to remember what are the "Divisibility rules" for those numbers

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the divisibility rules. Is there a more systematic way to check?

Comment: I can't imagine anything more systematic than the division rules for $8$ and $9$.

Comment: The 'other way' is to start checking the results of $72*i$, when $i=1,2,3,...$, and find the first one which answering the sequence. that's systematic but i wouldn't advise that

Comment: Try this number $$123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $a_k$ be formed by concatenating $1,2,3,...,k$, the residues of the $a_k$ $\pmod{9}$ repeat cyclically: $1,3,6,1,6,3,1,0,0$.

So $a_k$ will be divisible by $9$ if and only if $k$ is congruent to $8$ or $9 \pmod{9}$.  This should cut down your search field quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you. May I know what you mean by concatenating $1,2,3,...,k$?

Comment: Concatenating means just sticking them together as strings and interpreting the result as an integer.  For instance if we concatenate the numbers 23, 17, and 689, we get the number 2317689.

Comment: If $k$ is congruent to $8$ (mod 9), why is it divisible by $9?$

Comment: Anyways, thanks for the observation on the cyclic residues. I have used that to figure out the answer!

Comment: @Alexy Vincenzo Because $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8\equiv 0 \pmod{9}$.

Comment: What about the residues of numbers like $1234567891,  12345678910, 123456789101 \ ?$

Comment: $1234567891$ isn't of interest because it ends in mid number.

Comment: Hmm, what if ending in mid number is allowed?

Comment: Then the answer might be different. But I didn't think that was allowed in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well a natural number can be written as $$N=9k+S$$ where S is sum of digits. So it is divisible by 9 if there  sum is. And for 8 ($2^3$) we need last 3 digits divisible by 8.And simply we need both conditions for divisibility by 72.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see the comment by paw88789

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=123\cdots n$. Modulo $9$, a number leaves the same remainder as the sum of its digits, so $a_n$ is divisible by $9$ if and only if $1+2+\cdots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is. Thus, either $n$ or $n+1$ is a multiple of $9$. Modulo $8$, the last three digits $a_n$ leave the same remainder as $a_n$ (since $8$ divides $1000$) so in particular $n$ is even.

The only option when $n$ has 1 digit is $n=8$, which does not work since $678$ leaves a remainder of $2$ modulo $4$. Thus $n$ has at least $2$ digits, so by considering the last two digits of $a_n$ we see that $n$ must be a multiple of $4$. After $8$, the least multiple of $4$ that is either a multiple of $9$, or $1$ less than a multiple of $9$ is $n=36$, which works since $536$ is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 0):

Hope its help.
you can add $1+2+3+4+5+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$$1+2+3+4+5+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=9k \to n(n+1)=18k$$check the possible numbers.
for example $8*9=18k$ but $12345678\neq 8q\\$.
next possiblities $9*10 \to 123456789\neq 8q $
...

$17*18\to 1234567891011121314151617\neq 8q\\18*19...$